# SQL NTILE with even distribution

Tags: sql

I am trying to use the NTILE function to distribute the list (table below) evenly to X number of associates.

The order of importance is **GROUP** primary, followed by secondary and tertiary. **PRIORITY** would come next and should be assigned from lowest number to the highest.

```
PRIORITY   GROUP
1          primary
1          primary
1          primary
1          secondary
2          secondary
3          secondary
1          tertiary
1          tertiary
```

```
SELECT 
    NTILE(3) OVER(PARTITION BY GROUP, PRIORITY ORDER BY PRIORITY ASC) AS ASSOCIATE,
    PRIORITY, GROUP
FROM TABLE;
```

**Result:**

```
ASSOCIATE   PRIORITY   GROUP
1           1          primary
1           1          secondary
1           2          secondary
1           3          secondary
1           1          tertiary
2           1          primary
2           1          tertiary
3           1          primary
```

When partitioning with **GROUP** and **PRIORITY** in my NTILE function, I'm trying to avoid reassigning back from 1 before reaching to the last employee, instead should pick up from where it's left off so all 3 associates would have the same number of assignments.

**Desired output:**

```
ASSOCIATE   PRIORITY    GROUP
1           1           primary
1           1           secondary
1           1           tertiary
2           1           primary
2           2           secondary
2           1           tertiary
3           1           primary
3           3           secondary
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want `ntile()` for this.  I think you just want to enumerate the values in each group and then order them appropriately.  This produces the results that you specify:

```
select row_number() over (partition by grp order by priority) as seqnum, t.*
from t
order by 1, (case grp when 'primary' then 1 when 'secondary' then 2 else 3 end);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=38d922102380c3d0c49644bd6447884f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This worked. But how would I be able to utilize this but with but a dynamic number of associates that I can control/adjust within the query? If I want it to distribute evenly to 7, 5, 4, or any number of associates.

Comment: @WayneWong . . . This should work for any number of "groups". If it doesn't ask another question with a clear explanation of the logic you need.